# How to log error message in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, error-logging

How to log our **own error messages**(for ex: error due to invalid user date entry) which is generated in *php* program to **drupal error log**.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the [`watchdog` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/watchdog/6) :

```
watchdog($type, $message, $variables = array(), $severity = WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL)
```

Quoting the manual, the parameters are :

- `$type` The category to which this message belongs.
- `$message` The message to store in the log.
- `$variables` Array of variables to replace in the message on display or NULL if message is already translated or not possible to translate.
- `$severity` The severity of the message, as per RFC 3164
- `$link` A link to associate with the message.

And the error levels can be found on the page of [`watchdog_severity_levels`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/watchdog_severity_levels/6). For an error, you'll most probably use `WATCHDOG_ERROR`, or maybe even something more "critical", depending on the kind of error.

Comment: `$type` is generally the name of the module you are developing.

Answer (score 12):

Drupal 8+

```
// Logs a notice
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message);
// Logs an error
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($message);
```

See more examples at [How to Log Messages in Drupal 8](https://drupalize.me/blog/201510/how-log-messages-drupal-8).

Comment: I'm trying to log an entire "$form" and I can't

Comment: for example, you can log it old school using `$message = 'My form: <pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>;`

Comment: missing ' from milkovsky's comment `$message = 'My form: <pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>';`

Answer (score 6):

1) Indeed, watchdog is a standard way to record own PHP errors.

2) Alternatively, if you need to immediately see error messages while debugging your Drupal pages, you may want to see them logged/printed right at the related page - in FireBug console.
Sometimes is this very convenient when you can see page-related just-in-time logs.
This requires - [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension to FireFox and possibly [Firephp](http://firephp.org).

You can use the dfb() function to write log messages directly to the general Firebug console.

```
dfb($input, $label = NULL)
```

If you want to keep your Drupal-related log messages out of the normal Firebug console, you can write messages to the [Drupal for Firebug](http://drupal.org/project/drupalforfirebug) log with the firep() function:

```
firep($item, $optional_title)
```

Comment: Just installed the Drupal for Firebug extension - pretty sweet.

Answer (score 5):

Watchdog is the way to go for a production system no doubt but during debugging I find the `drupal_set_message` function useful.

It outputs the message to the screen where the 'Operation Successful'-type messages are normally displayed (so make sure you remove them before making the site Live).

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_set_message/6

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 7 we can log message by following method:

drupal  watchdog function we can use to log message  in database , make sure we have enabled optional core module for Database Logging at /admin/build/modules.

```
watchdog($type, $message, $variables = array(), $severity = WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL)
```

**$type:**
The category to which this message belongs , Example: PHP,cron.., we can filter message by type.

**$message :**
The message to store in the log,Example: 'The following module is missing from the file system: security_review'

**$variables :**
Array of variables to replace in the message on display or NULL if message is already translated or not possible to translate.
to make  message  translated , do not pass dynamic value pass variables in the message should be added by using placeholder strings.

**Example:**
watchdog('cg_volunteer', 'cg in form_alter %formly', array('%formly' => $form['#id']), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, $link = NULL);

**$severity**
The severity of the message,logs can be filter by severity as per RFC 3164. Possible values are WATCHDOG_ERROR, WATCHDOG_WARNING, etc.
For more example see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x

**$link**:
A link to associate with the message.

**Example**

// for logs notices

```
watchdog('my_module', $message, array());
```

// for Loging Error

```
watchdog('my_module', $message, array(), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
```

**In drupal 8 we used following method:**

// For Logs a notice.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($message);
```

// For Logs an error.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->error($message);
```

// For Alert, action must be taken immediately.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->alert($message);
```

// For Critical message.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->critical($message);
```

// For Debug-level messages.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->debug($message);
```

//For Emergency, system is unusable.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->emergency($message);
```

//For Warning

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->warning($message);
```

//For Informational messages.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->info($message);
```

Also for translate we should not use t() function.

```
\Drupal::logger('my_module')->alert('Message from @module: @message.', [
'@module' => $module,
'@message' => $message,
]);
```

this will be translated on run time.

**Example :**

```
\Drupal::logger('content_entity_example')->notice('@type: deleted %title.',
array(
'@type' => $this->entity->bundle(),
'%title' => $this->entity->label(),
));
```

Comment: How do you add a link?

Answer (score 2):

Both `watchdog` for D7 & `\Drupal::logger` for D8 will write log in `watchdog` table (in your database), and with **HUGE data logged**, you can imagine performance impact.

You can use `error_log` php function to do it (see [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-log.php)).

```
error_log("Your message", 3, "/path/to/your/log/file.log");
```

> You need to have permission to write in your log file (`/path/to/your/log/file.log`)

[drupal-8](/questions/tagged/drupal-8)[drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal)[php](/questions/tagged/php)[log](/questions/tagged/log)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Get logger factory.
$logger = \Drupal::service('logger.factory');

// Log a message with dynamic variables.
$nodeType = 'Article';
$userName = 'Admin';
$logger->get($moduleName)->notice('A new "@nodeType" created by %userName.', [
    '@nodeType' => $nodeType,
    '%userName' => $userName,
]);
```

[Source](https://github.com/BoldizArt/UsefulDrupal8Functions/blob/master/LoggingInDrupal8.php)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for how to do this with the arguments.