# Drupal error page

Tags: drupal

I would like to create a custom error page in Drupal 7. There are things like `set_message`, but they don't log the errors. So is there any hook or something similar to catch the error, log it and display a human error to my users?

Comment: found something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705840/how-to-log-error-message-in-drupal

Comment: let me  know if it works out for you . If not then we can work  on something better

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you saying you want to capture errors reported by 'set_message' and redirect users to a dedicated error page? If so, that would probably break a lot of default drupal functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated above that your goal is "catch the error, log it and display a human error to my users".

In that case you're probably looking for the functionality Try/Catch which allows you to try to run a block of code and if something goes wrong it will display a message.

In your particular case you can log the error to Drupal's database logging system with the watchdog function http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7

Optionally you could also log this to the PHP error_log as well see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Then you could continue on displaying the message to the user using the drupal_set_message function that you already figured out.

The final code for what you're trying to accomplish would look something like this:

```
try {

  // RUN YOUR CUSTOM CODE HERE

} catch (Exception $e) {

  // Record the error Drupal's database log
  watchdog('error_page', $e->getMessage());

  // Record the error to PHP's error_log
  error_log($e->getMessage());

  // Display a message to the user
  drupal_set_message("We're sorry, but we couldn't find the page you were looking for.", 'error');
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! I'll try it as soon as I can!

Answer (score 0):

[drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7) could be used to fetch an array to iterate through for the the error types of messages.

I'm not sure I made 100% sense of your question, but since you referenced drupal_set_message() i thought this might be what you were looking for.

You could handle it in hook_init(), check for messages there, if you find any, do something with it.

Redirecting on an error though could potentially break default drupal functionality like forms.