# In the drupal 7 rules module's execute custom php action how can I find out what the $site variable specifically contains?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-rules

To preface, I am relatively new to php.
I need to use the 'execute custom php' action in the rules module to set the value of one of my user fields, but I haven't been able to figure out how to access that field from the $site variable that is available. I know how to print_r the contents of $site and find what I am looking for from there(and I have used that before in nodes successfully), but since I am in the rules module if I just print_r($site) the result doesn't show up anywhere that I know of. What is a good way to find out the contents of the $site variable?

I apologize if this is not clear!

Comment: Don't apologize - make it clear :)

Comment: Touche :) This is the answer someone else gave on another site (I can't post an answer to my own question for 8 hours since I don't have 10 reputation.) "Maybe you can log it to the screen with [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) or to the drupal logs with [watchdog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705840/how-to-log-error-message-in-drupal)."                                                                      I used drupal_set_message and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer someone else gave on another site: "Maybe you can log it to the screen with [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) or to the drupal logs with [watchdog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705840/how-to-log-error-message-in-drupal)." I used drupal_set_message and it worked.